# How to insert 2 million characters?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to insert 2 million characters in an Oracle database, but when I try to insert with a CLOB I have an error because its very long. 
How can I insert 2 million characters in a field?

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA_CLOB(id number, valor CLOb default EMPTY_CLOB());
insert into TABLA_CLOB(id, valor) values (1,'DOCUMENT: ');

DECLARE
  v_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT valor into v_clob from TABLA_CLOB where id=1 for update;
  dbms_lob.writeappend(v_clob,200,'text with 2 million characters');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_clob);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: It might be easier to have the text in a file and read it from the file into a CLOB, rather than trying to embed the value in a script?

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL & SQL, `'a value'` is a text literal and [the SQL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm) states:

> Text literals have properties of both the `CHAR` and `VARCHAR2` datatypes:
>
> - Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the datatype `CHAR` by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics.
> - A text literal can have a maximum length of 4000 bytes.

Or for [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/literal.htm#LNPLS01326):

> A string literal can hold up to 32,767 characters.

Split your `'text with 2 million characters'` into 4k or 32k chunks and append each of those.